# Workflow Manager stopped processing workflows after AAM modification

Tags: workflow

After I modified alternative access mapping my workflow manager stopped working.
My workflows are started but stuck on first stage. I can see that Workflow manager is trying to get item data from external URL.

After returning back the AAM settings the Workflow Manager don't refresh the url.